# Unicode for showing smileys

Tags: ios

I have found unicode's for most of the smileys. But i am having problems for showing some smileys like '`:yum:`', '`:innocent:`' and '`:no_mouth:`'. Unable to find what is the unicode for them.

Can someone tell me how this unicode works ?

Comment: Have a look at the [Unicode chart for emoticons](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf) or the [corresponding Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_%28Unicode_block%29).

Comment: [No mouth](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F636/index.htm "fileformat.info") [Innocent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/innocent/index.htm "fileformat.info") [Yum](http://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/yum/index.htm "fileformat.info") You can find others on the web site http://fileformat.info

Comment: Okay but what i have entered are completely different starting with '\ueXXX'. So how would i map this to '1F636'? Sorry new to this.